# Create a profile example with emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Im tried to create a example with emberjs, but i cant show the information over the view.

**code**
http://jsfiddle.net/FzRb2/1/

**feature**: I want to create a profile view, that show me the information contain in amodel in the controller (its not a form just a list of his attributes.

1. I create a model , controller, tempate and a view.
2. create a object over the content variable in controller tried to bindind in the view and show this....but never saw it :(

please some one can help me with my question...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/FzRb2/2/

Comment: yeap, but i  have another project with emberjs and i just create the view and append that view to a specific div. i dont know how to do that in this example:

Comment: You would add your view via `view.appendTo('#id')`, see http://jsfiddle.net/Q24k4/

Comment: THANK!!. but.. i have something more (sorry). my idea was use binding attr from the view with the controller information  example i the view listBinding: "Test.userController.content". is that posible?